# OOP Composition - Dealing with classes as separate instances and circular objects

Tags: php, oop

I have an object in PHP with a composition of objects like:

```
// Settlement (DB Fields: id, name)
id = 1, name = 'Meep', jobs = array()
-
// Job (DB Fields: id, action, settlement_id)
id = 1, action = 'build'
```

So I can do something like: `$settlement->getJobs()` and it'll return an array of `jobs`

When it comes to processing these jobs though I need to know the Settlement as well. So I'm kind of confused as to how it should exist.

Should a `Job` contain a `Settlement` and then do something like: `$job->getSettlement()` or would there be an infinite loop of nesting/composition?

Or when I get the instance from the database to process the job, should I first get the `Settlement` object containing the `Job` that's to be processed so it's in the same as before?

Within my database the `Job` is attached to the `Settlement` via foreign key `settlement_id` so within my `Job` entity I wasn't sure if I should be storing just `settlement_id` or the entire `Settlement` but then there's the nesting/composition loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable for nodes to link to each other. You can have an instance of the `Settlement` whose `Job` it is inside of the `Job` object.

Comment: thanks, This is one of those things that people don't really teach because it's regarded as obvious :P